# Issue with creating CONNECTION MANAGER IN TALEND USING SQL SERVER

Tags: java, sql-server, talend

while try to connect with my DB . I'm getting some popup window to download some .jar files. But for a single file I can't to download it. Please say how to resolve this issue. I'm getting error code for missing file

"mvn:org.talend.libraries/mssql-jdbc/6"

Error Screenshot in below link :

[image]

Comment: do this and i will tell you what to do : Window->Preferences->general->network Connections       .   Please take a picture and post it in the question i will tell you what do then ! Because your are probably passing by a proxy that why you cannot establish http connexion ;)

Comment: Try in the active provider : Manual and test if the download work or not

Answer (score 0):

You can find this driver on microsoft website if download from talend is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

do this  `Window->Preferences->general->network Connections`

Try in the  `active provider : Manual` and test if the download work or not